# MVC partial view or base viewmodel for multiple controllers showing same data?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm (finally) moving from WebForms to MVC and questions are arising, and seems I cannot find a good solution...

Say I have in the _layout.cshtml page a "widget" that shows the last 4 messages for the logged user. This is present in every controller of the site.

How should I proceed?

a) BaseViewModel: For every controller and **every action** I have to create the specific viewmodel that inherits from BaseViewModel and in every controller I set data + the last 4 message in the baseviewModel:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   HomeViewModel h = new HomeViewModel();
   h.UserName = "Daniele"; //in BaseViewModel
   h.LastMessages = _messagesRepository.GetLastItems(4); //in BaseViewModel

   //Other data specific to index page

   return View(h);
}

public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
   HomeViewModel h = new HomeViewModel();
   h.UserName = "Daniele"; //in BaseViewModel
   h.LastMessages = _messagesRepository.GetLastItems(4); //in BaseViewModel

   //Other data specific to dashboard

   return View(h);
}
```

b) Html Action: Seems a better solution but in every controller I still have to copy&paste the

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public PartialViewResult LastMessages()
{
  //Code
}
```

in every controller I'll create.

What is the best pratice? Suggestion?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can specify the controller with `Html.Action`

Comment: Use a `[ChildActionOnly]` method, but it only needs to be in one of you controllers (say `MessagesController`), and then in the layout use `@{ Html.RenderAction("LastMessages", "Messages"); }`

Answer (score 0):

a) in 2017 i highly recommend you look at angular.js or react js

b) In absence of that, add jQuery to the project. Create a partial that will on `$(document).ready()` call to ONE action that will provide the 4 items.
This code will exist only once and work from everywhere.

Comment: Interesting! But.. just out of curiosity if I want to avoid using javascript, a and b are the only 2 options available to solve my question? Thanks.

Comment: I see now you gave me an answer for both options. In your opinion, which one is the best to start with? A or B?

Comment: @DanieleArrighi If you want to avoid using JavaScript you could try using an ASP.Net control with a code behind and render that. Unfortunately my expertise in the are is not great so i can't explain much. 

In terms of starting with - depends on how much you've already got. If you're over 40% of your project, just add jQuery. You can easily augment the MVC views with it and it won't change the basic principles of how your code works. If you're just getting started, consider if you have an extra month to add to the timeline, and if you do - start with a frontend framework.